# JPA multiselect returns null in joined return values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My simplified model is:

- `Player`, who can play games,
- `Game`, which can be played by a player multiple times,
- `Score` a player received playing given game

In my entity mapping, relationship between `Game` and `Score` is bidirectional, but `Player` does not map a collection of all its `Score`s, there is only a `Score => Player` relationship. My JPA provider is Hibernate, and my relationship mappings use default `FetchType` (i.e. have no explicit value for `FetchType` and probably use lazy, because that's the default for Hibernate, despite of the JPA standard).

Now I want to count how many times every Player *p* played every Game *g* and omit ones played just a few times, and I came up with following query:

```
SELECT p, g, COUNT(s.id)
FROM Score s JOIN 
     s.game g JOIN
     s.player p
WHERE *some additional filtering criteria, like games not being private etc*
GROUP BY p, g 
HAVING COUNT(s.id) >= :minimumGamesToQualify
```

When I run following code:

```
String strQuery = ...query above...;
Query query = em.createQuery(strQuery);
query.setParameter("criteriaParam", criteriaValue);
List result = query.getResultList();
```

Returned list contains (as expected) rows of `Object[ ]`, but returned values for `p` and `g` are always `null` (but counts are calculated correctly and have expected values). But when I change first line of the query to `SELECT p.id, g.id, COUNT(s.id)`, returned rows contain expected IDs for `p` and `g`.
I understand it might happen because of lazy fetch of references, but how can I force the query to retrieve `p` and `g` despite of being mapped as lazy? Can I do it with `JOIN FETCH` somehow?

**EDIT:** Simplified mappings and query call (removed parts that IMO are not relevant to the question):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"Scores\"")
public class Score extends AbstractEntity {

    private String name;
    private Date scored_on;

    public Score() { }

    @Basic public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @Basic public Date getScored_on() { return scored_on; }
    public void setScored_on(Date scored_on) { this.scored_on = scored_on; }

    private Game game;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Game getGame() { return game; }
    public void setGame(Game game) { this.game = game; }

    private Player player;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="player_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Player getPlayer() { return player; }
    public void setPlayer(Player player) { this.player = player; }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="\"Games\"")
@XmlRootElement
public class Game extends AbstractEntity {

    private String name;
    @Basic public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName (String  name) { this.name = name; }

    public Game() {    }

    private List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();

    @XmlTransient
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="game")
    public List<Score> getScores() { return scores; }
    public void setScores(List<Score> scores) { this.scores = scores; }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="\"Players\"")
public class Player extends AbstractEntity {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;

    public Player() { }

    @Basic public String getFirstname() { return firstname; }
    @Basic public String getLastname()  { return lastname; }
    @Basic public String getEmail()     { return email; }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) { this.firstname = firstname; }
    public void setLastname(String lastname)   { this.lastname = lastname; }
    public void setEmail(String email)         { this.email = email; }

}

String strRelevantGamesQuery = "SELECT p, g, COUNT(s.Id) FROM Score s JOIN s.game g JOIN s.player p WHERE s.scored_on <= :scoredBefore GROUP BY p, g HAVING COUNT(s.Id) >= :minimumGamesPlayes";
TypedQuery<Object[]> queryRelevantGames = em.createQuery(strRelevantGamesQuery, Object[].class);
queryRelevantGames.setParameter("minimumGamesPlayes", 5L);
queryRelevantGames.setParameter("scoredBefore", summaryDate);
List<Object[]> resultRelevantGames = queryRelevantGames.getResultList();

//resultRelevantGames is a list of Object[3]. All row[0] and row[1] objects are null, row[2] contains correctly calculated counts.
//When I change query to: 
//    String strRelevantGamesQuery = "SELECT p.Id, g.Id, COUNT(s.Id) FROM...
//then all row[0] and row[1] contain correct IDs
```

Comment: values for `p` and `g` should never be `null` - can you show us a sample code?

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski added mappings and query invocation.

Comment: I have created a project with your mappings, filled db with sample data and resulting array does not contain null values, try upgrading hibernate/spring (if used) version